# What does "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest tests/" line mean and why is it needed

Tags: node.js, jestjs, package.json

While setting up Jest and React Testing Library for React and TypeScript I found a blog where it was mentioned to set

```json
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest tests/"
```

in the `package.json` under `scripts`.

I was wondering what the entire line represents and why they are needed. I only used `test: "jest"` before. I know that when the command `npm test` runs, that line under `scripts` will execute (mostly to run the jest test runner to run all the tests). When will `test: "jest"` do and when will  `"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest tests/"` be needed?

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env (but suggests the author was unaware of [what Jest does](https://jestjs.io/docs/environment-variables#node_env)), https://jestjs.io/docs/cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a script in `package.json`. It lets you run a complex command by typing a simple command on the command-line. You would execute this script by running `npm run test`.

Scripts in `package.json` can contain commands that are supplied by the operating system, or that are supplied by Node.js packages. The `cross-env` command is supplied by the Node package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

`cross-env NODE_ENV=test` -- The purpose of the `cross-env` command is to set an environment variable (in this case, to set the variable `NODE_ENV` to the value of `test`) in an operating system-independent way, so that the same command works on both linux and Windows and Mac.

`jest tests/` -- The second to last word of the command (`jest`) runs the [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) test runner, and `tests/` tells Jest where to find the test files. Jest will take these test files (unit tests) and run them, and report the success or failure of these tests.

Answer (score 0):

Under `scripts` inside a package.json file you can define any commands that maybe useful.

Where key is a user defined name and command is a process to run.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "key": "command"
    }
}
```

Normally to run a script with npm you input in a termanial `npm run key`. But `test` is a special case that npm understands and you can ommit `run` and just type `npm test` as a shorthand.

Other script keys can be useful if you want to define deferent testing processes that test parts of an application or generates code coverage. You can create new commands `test:ci` or `test:coverage`. And invoke them with `npm run test:ci` or `npm run test:coverage`. These commands need `run` to be included in the arguments.

As for the command, its first calling a process `cross-env`. Looking up [that package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) its used to support environment variables across platforms.

That previous command allows the next part `NODE_ENV=test` to run cross platform and sets the `NODE_ENV` to `test` which might have special meaning to the application. `NODE_ENV` when not in `production` mode does some extra logging, is debuggable and consumes slightly more memory.

You are already familiar with the next command, which is the `jest` process which runs test.

The last part is an argument to `jest` telling it where to look for tests. Inside a folder `tests/`.

EDIT: This may not be needed in your application. If you're happy with `test: "jest"` it's fine to use.